# How to show all the midpoints on my bisection code?

Tags: matlab, bisection

I have a code for finding the bisection (and it finally works!), but I need to include 3 more things:

- output- Root History a vector containing the sequence of midpoints obtained by the algorithm
- output- the absolute value of the function
- f(x) at r, i.e., fRoot = f(r) input- max iterations

  ```
  function [R, E] = myBisection(f, a, b, tol)
      m = (a + b)/2;
      R = m;
      E = abs(f(m));
      while E(end) > tol
          if sign(f(a)) == sign(f(m))
              a = m;
          else
              b = m;
          end
          m = (a + b)/2;
          R = [R, m];
          E = [E, abs(f(m))];
      end
  ```

how do I do this? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected indents an you can see that you've left out `end` from the end of the function. (it is optional but best not to leave those things out so you know you did not mean to write couple lines to the end but you forgot it.)

`R` and `E` should be returned now, if you call myBisection apropriately, that is

```
[R, E] = myBisection(f, a, b, tol);
```

If you just call

```
myBisection(f, a, b, tol)
```

it will only return `R`.

To add a limit on the number of iterations, you change `while`'s condition like so:

```
iter=0;
while (E(end) > tol) && (iter<max_iter)
    iter = iter+1;
    % ...

end
```

or it is better to do it in a for loop, with an `if` plus `break`:

```
for iter=1:max_iter
    if(E(end) <= tol), break, end;
    % ...
end
```

Comment: Just one remark: The `end` keyword for functions is optional in MATLAB. (As far as I know, the `endfunction` in Octave is not optional, though)

Comment: @Thilo it is just `end`, just checked, my Matlab does not accept `endfunction` or `end function`. Nonetheless I think we agree that it is better not to leave out `end`'s though, and to use correct indents.

Comment: `endfunction` is the Octave keyword, not MATLAB, and it should be required in Octave. Correct indentation is crucial, yes, we agree on that ;)